# Python 3.4.1 invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I was doing a program that showed several prime numbers,is necessary to use functions.
For example 1 at 10 = 2,3,5,7

but appear   an error in the last line in the - print i- only ... I can't understand what is that

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False

    i = 2
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
        if (num % i == 0):
            return False

    return True

def main():
    print ("this program do prime numbers")
    start = int(raw_input("start number "))
    finish = int(raw_input('finish number: '))

    for i in range(start,finish):
        if isPrime(i):
            print i
```

Comment: I find it helps to google error messages.  `python print syntax error` would have solved the problem.  (Note that there are other issues here-- you'll get a NameError from `raw_input`, for example, but googling will solve that too.)

Comment: @nneonneo - so, thinked is this too, but I tried to change, but not works

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: @Tom Dalton -  invalid syntax error,it indicates the i, but tried to change for (i), but the same error appear ... I can't understand what's wrong

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - I think I didn't understand well ... sorry

Comment: @DSM - I researched a lot but I haven't found anything like my error T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not surrounding the `i` in `print i` with parentheses. [In Python 3, `print` has been changed from a statement to a function.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) Here is your edited code:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False

    i = 2
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
        if (num % i == 0):
            return False

    return True

def main():
    print ("this program do prime numbers")
    start = int(raw_input("start number "))
    finish = int(raw_input('finish number: '))

    for i in range(start,finish):
        if isPrime(i):
            print(i) #Previously "print i"
```

Previously running:

```
bash-3.2$ python3.4 prime.py
  File "test.py", line 19
    print i
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
bash-3.2$
```

After editing:

```
bash-3.2$ python3.4 prime.py
bash-3.2$
```